# Is there a way to extract a report of or script all of the primary keys in a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, primary-key

I have just discovered that deployed copies of one of our databases have no primary keys. This is probably the fault of the SSMS Import/Export wizard, which has done the same to me. Our master copy of the schema still has primary keys, and I would like to generate a script that will add those keys to any deployed databases without them.

The best I can hope for is to just do something to script all primary keys, but I will be happy to also just extract the names of the columns that make up these keys and generate my own script.

Comment: Only the primary keys are missing? Have you checked Unique, Foreign Key and other (`CHECK`) constraints?

Comment: @ypercube I was about to add that other indexes are missing. I haven't seen anything else missing, but I'm on table 30 or so of 653 tables. I am certain this is the work of the SSMS Export/Import wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (SELECT obj.name + '.' +col.name as colName, idx.name, idx.is_unique, idx.is_primary_key, idx.is_unique_constraint
  FROM 
    sys.indexes idx INNER JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON idx.object_id = obj.object_id INNER JOIN
    sys.index_columns idxcol ON idxcol.index_id = idx.index_id AND idxcol.object_id = idx.object_id INNER JOIN
    sys.columns col ON col.column_id=idxcol.column_id AND col.object_id = idxcol.object_id
  WHERE obj.type_desc NOT IN ('SYSTEM_TABLE', 'INTERNAL_TABLE')) a
WHERE a.is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I found it's not just PK's, but all indexes, so if I leave there 'where clause' off, I have 533 missing indexes.

Comment: @ProfK then why did you accept the answer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I asked about primary keys, and Matt gave a satisfactory answer about primary keys. You figure it out.

Comment: @ProfK sorry, I thought you were saying here and above that the answer didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

i did find this resource when looking for how to export keys.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/

Comment: Please don't add link-only answers.

Comment: Well its too long to past the entire code.